# Validators for wtforms do not pass into my inputs in the html which causes all validations to be pushed to the server

Tags: python, jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am following [this tutorial.](https://blog.carsonevans.ca/2019/08/20/validating-ajax-requests-with-wtforms-in-flask/) It all works great except it does not pass the validators into my html which causes all validations to be analyzed server side.

Here is an example of what it should do:

```
<input class="form-control is-invalid" id="username" maxlength="15" minlength="3" name="username" type="text" value="">
```

Instead I get something like this:

```
<input class="form-control is-invalid" id="username" name="username" type="text" value="">
```

Without the Min/Max length validators the client side does not check validation and everything is pushed to the server to validate.

Here is some of my code:
forms.py:

```
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    body = TextField('body', [DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=10)])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

post.html this is likely the problem side. I can manually place min/max into form.body and it works, but for some reason it does not generate it automatically.

```
    <form id="post_template">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <!--<div class="text-danger my-2" id="csrf_token-error"></div>-->
        <div class="post_comment">
            <img class="profile_image" src="{{ current_user.avatar(30) }}"/>
            {{ form.body.label }}
            {{ form.body(class='comment_input', placeholder='Make a post...') }}
            <div id="body-error" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>Add to post...</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ form.submit(class='form-control btn btn-secondary') }}
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: What version of WTForms? Try with StringField instead of TextField.

Comment: My WTForms version was 2.1 now it is 3.0.1 and my flask-wtf was 0.15.1 now it's 1.0.0 and doing that fixed my issue! Thanks a lot! If you post that as the answer I'll give you the answer upvote.

Comment: Probable reason why from [WTForm 3 changes](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/whats_new/?highlight=textfield): "The TextField alias for StringField is deprecated."

Comment: Good chance it was that. When I upgraded it threw that exact error so I changed all the TextField's out.